# TWA address bar still not hidden but assetLink works

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, twa

I published my TWA-App to Google Play and the address bar on the top is still visible. The Sha256 appears in the google console, if I generate it with the keytool and if I use the assetLink creator in Android Studio. So it has to be the right one. As recommended I checked with the adb command from the github repository and googles article and got: "*I cr_OriginVerifier: Verification succeeded.*". Of course the site uses https and I checked if the link redirects. I reseted all chrome flags.

Chrome 78
Android 9

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after I gave up, someday I realised that all the links I open, get open in my App and without the address bar. I changed the Sha256 from the generated by the keytool to the from the App store and reinstalled the app as the production release. Then the address bar showed up again and now after some days it disappeared again. In the end, waiting solved the problem on my phone but the address bar is still on my tablet and some friend installed it and he has the address bar, too :/

Comment: Personally I done a mistake: I use my own key fingerprint instead of the one gave by Google in my /.well-known/assetlinks.json. Verify your are currently using the Google key in release pane > app signing key. This mean that the URL bar will be shown in development mode, but in production it will match and then the URL bar will disappear.
Then test it on a published (e.g. testing release) after having resetting chrome.

Comment: Thanks @Bastien Adam, I already use the app signing key from the google console and a published release. I didn't change anything since last time, but the address bar suddenly disappeared on my Tablet. I hope it works on any device now.

Comment: @BastienAdam so you mean that it's also shown on beta releases even not deployed for debugging ?